# how to fix the netty-handler violation from aqua scanner report under application insights

Tags: java, maven, security, netty, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm facing the netty-handler violation from aqua scanner report for my maven project, where the parent path is showing as /applicationinsights-agent.jar. No fix version is suggested,

to fix this I excluded the netty-handler from the applicationinsights-agent maven dependency in pom.xml file

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>applicationinsights-agent</artifactId>
       <version>${applicationinsights-agent.version}</version>  (*I added the latest version 3.4.18*)
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
               <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

But this is not resolving, looking for a solution